# If $R:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$ is a irrational rotation, $\{R^{n}([x])\}$ is dense in $S^{1}$ for all points.

Tags: general-topology, circles, rotations, irrational-numbers

Let $\alpha$ a irrational number, and $R:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$ the irrational rotation, i.e., $[x]\rightarrow[x+\alpha]$. I need to prove that, for all $[x]\in S^{1}$, the set $\{R^{n}([x])\}$ is dense in $S^{1}$.

First, I can write $R$ by

$$R(e^{2\pi ix})=e^{2\pi i (x+\alpha)}.$$

So, I can write $R^{n}(x)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ by

$$R^{n}(e^{2\pi i x})=e^{2\pi i(x+n\alpha)} $$

I need to prove that, for all $e^{2\pi i x}\in S^{1}$ and for all $[y]=e^{2\pi i y}\in S^{1}$, every neighborhood $V$ of $[y]$ contains a point $[z_{y}]=e^{2\pi i z}$ such that $[z_y]=R^{n}([x])$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. That is,

$e^{2\pi i z}=e^{2\pi i (x+\alpha n)}\Rightarrow 2\pi iz=2\pi i(x+\alpha n)+2ik\pi\;\textrm{for some}\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow z=x+\alpha n+k.$

Is my way correct? If it does, how can I proceed now? If it doesn't, what I need to do?

I don't think this question is duplicate. I'm showing my attempt to proof, that is different from other proofs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the orbit of an iterated rotation of 0 (by (A)(Pi), A irrational) around a circle centered at the origin is dense in the circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282102/prove-that-the-orbit-of-an-iterated-rotation-of-0-by-api-a-irrational-aro) or [Algebraic proof that a set generated by irrational rotations is dense in $S^1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374030/algebraic-proof-that-a-set-generated-by-irrational-rotations-is-dense-in-s1)

Comment: I am showing my attempt to proof, and this attempt does not occurs in that questions. I think that is not duplicate

Comment: To answer your question "Is my way correct?", the answer is no, because you must explain why the point $[z_y]$ exists in the set $V$ and satisfies the appropriate properties, but you have not done that; in fact, once the sentence "That is..." starts, the set $V$ is never mentioned again. To answer your question "If it doesn't...", read one of other proofs linked in the comments above.

Comment: You're nor using irrationality, so your attempt cannot be right,